# How to determine whether the phone was hung up locally or was hung up by the remote end?

Tags: android, phone-call

When an incoming call hangs up, how do you judge whether to hang up or hang up?
How do I monitor the hangup button on the phone page?
If you know the answer, please tell me, thank you！

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you can NOT do this.

But looking into DisconnectCause (android.telecom.DisconnectCause), maybe here has some help.

> ```
> /** Disconnected because of an unknown or unspecified reason. */
> public static final int UNKNOWN = 0;
> /** Disconnected because there was an error, such as a problem with the network. */
> public static final int ERROR = 1;
> /** Disconnected because of a local user-initiated action, such as hanging up. */
> public static final int LOCAL = 2;
> /**
>  * Disconnected because of a remote user-initiated action, such as the other party hanging up
>  * up.
>  */
> public static final int REMOTE = 3;
> /** Disconnected because it has been canceled. */
> public static final int CANCELED = 4;
> /** Disconnected because there was no response to an incoming call. */
> public static final int MISSED = 5;
> /** Disconnected because the user rejected an incoming call. */
> public static final int REJECTED = 6;
> /** Disconnected because the other party was busy. */
> public static final int BUSY = 7;
> /**
>  * Disconnected because of a restriction on placing the call, such as dialing in airplane
>  * mode.
>  */
> public static final int RESTRICTED = 8;
> /** Disconnected for reason not described by other disconnect codes. */
> public static final int OTHER = 9;
> ```

Sure there are much more reasons than local or remote hang-up.

Looking into android.telecom.ConnectionService, maybe some hack way can achieve your target.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This answer is helpful to me.